# Match Points with Nearest Routes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, network-analyst

I am using new route analysis in ArcMap. I am trying to find shorthest route between multiple points.

Some of the Points are not on the route, see green example in the picture below.

I am trying to match points which are not on the roads with nearest route. Is there a way to do this with ArcMap ?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Did you find any issue?